# Expression in SSRS Slowing down Report Rendering

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

An expression in my report is making the report to run very slowly. The expression, set in a Row Column Visibility Property is like so:

```
    =IIF(Parameters!View.Value = 1 AND (Fields!PastVal.Value = 0)AND(Fields!DatePay.Value = 0) AND 
    (Fields!Line.Value = 0),True, IIF(Parameters!View.Value = 2 AND Fields!TaxPaid.Value = "N",True, False))
```

Now this expression returns the right result. The problem is that it makes the report run very slow.

To test it, I took off the expression and reports are displayed in less than 3 seconds but with the expression on, report takes over 50 seconds to run. Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Unchecke the tablix page break option "Keep together on one page if possible" if it is checked.

Comment: That property is not checked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Using This Query check Which Step taking time for Report Processing:**

```
use ReportServer

select top 10 InstanceName,
                ItemPath,
                UserName,
                CAST((TimeDataRetrieval)as numeric(18,2))/60000 TimeDataRetrieval,
                CAST((TimeProcessing)as numeric(18,2))/60000 TimeProcessing,
                CAST((TimeRendering)as numeric(18,2))/60000 TimeRendering,
                CAST((TimeDataRetrieval+TimeProcessing+TimeRendering)as numeric(18,2))/ 60000 [Total_Time(Minutes)]
 from ExecutionLog3
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj. I ran the query against my ReportServer database and nothing was returned. I re-ran the report and tried several times but no data returned.